# Make a PyWinAuto Program wait for a popup with Python

Tags: python, popup, automation, wait, pywinauto

I've got a Python 2.7 script that uses PyWinAuto to automate an application.  At one point in the application, it goes off and does something for a long time...sometimes 15 seconds, sometimes up to 2 minutes...You never know...each time is different.

Once the process is finished, a popup appears, and I want PyWinAuto to continue on.  So, I'm trying to make the program wait and check if that popup dialog has appeared.  When it does, I try to break out of the loop.  Here's a look at the code that does what I'm describing:

```
all_done = 1
    while all_done != 1:
        try:
            app.Phazer.Static2.Texts() == [u'Would you like to Store Results?']
            all_done = 1
            break
        except:
            print("Testing...")
            time.sleep(2)

..rest of the code..
```

However, 80% of the time, it works every time....Otherwise, PyWinAuto sometimes jumps out of the loop and tries to work on the popup dialog that hasn't appeared yet.

I'm new to Python, but I know there has to be a smarter, more reliable way to pull this off....Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only case I can imagine is that app.Phazer.Static2 is matched with another control sometimes.

app.Phazer.Static2 is equivalent to app.Phazer.ChildWindow(best_match='Static2'). Best match algorithm used in pywinauto can capture another static text with similar name.

Comparison operator == does't raise any exception, so you may get incorrect static text, it will return False to nothing, all_done = 1, break. That's it.

You can make the following code to make sure you connected with appropriate control:

```
app.Phazer.ChildWindow(class_name='Static', ctrl_index=1)
```

or

```
app.Window_(title='Phazer', class_name='#32770').ChildWindow(class_name='Static', ctrl_index=1)
```

if you're in doubt with capturing dialog.

And so the final check should be

```
if app.Phazer.ChildWindow(class_name='Static', ctrl_index=1).Texts() != [u'Would you like to Store Results?']:
    raise Exception()
```